# Reading and Writing with Multiple Children C++ Unix

Tags: c++, unix

So, this is a follow up on my assignment I posted earlier. 
Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913617/piping-and-forking-in-c-in-unix

Got that section of the code all working now, but now I have to move onto 4 processes, which is giving me a hard time. Just as a recap, I have to take data files and have the sum of the integers added up using piping and forking. Currently I am having problems getting the sum to come up, if I put int mypipe[4] and change all my variables accordingly, my program freezes up. Currently trying two pipes, but only will show the sum of one of the pipes. Here is my code I have for the 4 process portion:

```
else
    {
            pid_t child1, child2, child3, child4;
            int mypipe1[2];
            int mypipe2[2];

            //File 1
            t1=clock();
            int temptotal=0;
            int file1[1000];
            for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                    infile1 >> file1[i];
            }

            pipe(mypipe1);
            pipe(mypipe2);
            //Begin the forking
            if((child1 = fork()) == 0)
            {
                    close(mypipe1[1]);
                    close(mypipe2[0]);
                    close(mypipe2[1]);
                    for(int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
                    {
                            temptotal = temptotal + file1[i];
                    }
                    write(mypipe1[0], &temptotal, sizeof(temptotal));
                    temptotal=0;
                    exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                    if((child2 =fork())==0)
                    {
                            close(mypipe1[0]);
                            close(mypipe2[1]);
                            close(mypipe2[0]);
                            for(int i =250; i < 500; i++)
                            {
                                    temptotal = temptotal + file1[i];
                            }
                            write(mypipe1[1], &temptotal, sizeof(temptotal));
                            temptotal=0;
                            exit(1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            if((child3=fork())==0)
                            {
                                    close(mypipe1[0]);
                                    close(mypipe1[1]);
                                    close(mypipe2[1]);
                                    for(int i =500; i < 750; i++)
                                    {
                                            temptotal = temptotal + file1[i];
                                    }
                                    write(mypipe2[0], &temptotal, sizeof(temptotal));
                                    temptotal=0;

                    exit(0);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    if((child4=fork())==0)
                                    {
                                            close(mypipe1[0]);
                                            close(mypipe1[1]);
                                            close(mypipe2[0]);
                                            for(int i =750; i < 1000; i++)
                                            {
                                                    temptotal = temptotal + file1[i];
                                            }
                                            write(mypipe2[1], &temptotal, sizeof(temptotal));
                                            temptotal=0;
                                            exit(1);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                            //Parent Proccess
                                            int n1,n2,n3,n4;
                                            read(mypipe1[0],&n1,sizeof(n1));
                                            close(mypipe1[0]);
                                            read(mypipe1[1],&n2,sizeof(n2));
                                            close(mypipe1[1]);
                                            read(mypipe2[0],&n3,sizeof(n3));
                                            close(mypipe2[0]);
                                            read(mypipe2[1],&n4,sizeof(n4));
                                            close(mypipe2[1]);

                                            total = n1+n2+n3+n4;
                                            std::cout<<"File1 sum: "<<total<<std::endl;
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

Any ideas what I am missing? Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
 pipe(mypipe1);
 pipe(mypipe2);
```

You're creating the pipes here. Later in the code:

```
 write(mypipe1[0], &temptotal, sizeof(temptotal));

 // ...

 read(mypipe1[1],&n2,sizeof(n2));
```

You've got things backwards.

`pipe()` puts the ***read*** side of the pipe into the first element of the array, #0, and the ***write*** side of the pipe into the second element of the array #1.  `mypipe1[0]` is the read end of the pipe. `mypipe1[1]` is the write end of the pipe.

Your code tries to read from the write side of each pipe, and write to the read end of each pipe.

And you had no idea that what the problem was because your code failed to diligently check the return values from `read()` or `write()`. Had you done so, you would've found out yourself that all your `read()`s and `write()`s were yelling at you, telling you that they failed miserably.

The lesson you learned today is: always check the error codes and return values from system calls, so that you know exactly when a problem occurs, and why, without having to ask for help on stackoverflow.com

This may not be the only problem with your code, but if you fix it, and you add proper error checking to all the other system calls, you should be able to easily find and solve any remaining problems.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'll see if that works. I wish I could have seen the errors, but in my Unix Vim program I'm using on the school machine doesn't show me them.

Comment: You mean that your "Unix Vim program" doesn't let you write `if (write( ... ) < 0) { perror("write failed, you silly goose!"); }`. That's a rather strange vim bug, if you ask me.